# How can I record Skype conversations?

Tags: skype

We are a small company and we have a help desk service to support our clients. We want to use Skype to provide voice live support. This is the easy part. What we need also, is to be able to record some of the conversations for training purposes.

What is the best way to implement such solution? We have a low budget, so we are looking for something very cheap or even free.

Ideally we would like to have something running in the background on our Ubuntu 10.10 desktops, and in someway detects the beginning of the conversation, starts the recording automatically, stops when the conversation is finished.

Comment: Are these just audio conversations, or both audio and video?

Comment: only audio for the moment.

Comment: Thank you mikewhatever and root45 for your answers. Both answers are about the same tool. We will install the tool and do some tests. What is worrying me a little is the icon in the system tray.   We will see if we will be able to control that. We do not want the people to manipulate the settings or anything that could influence the recording. We would like something like a background process or some role restrictions. Definitely we will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: If you want it in the BG, you could reroute the audio devices. So that a "sniffer" records from audio in and provides this as a virtual device. On the Mac, there is Soundflower, I do not know anything for Linux though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Skype Call Recorder.](http://atdot.ch/scr/) It can

- Record calls to MP3, Ogg Vorbis or WAV files
- Automatic and manual recording
- Configure automatic recording on per-caller basis
- Split stereo recording

and it's free.

You can install it by adding the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dajhorn/skype-call-recorder
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype-call-recorder
```

(Update 14.08.2015: The ppa does not seem to work any longer. Go to http://atdot.ch/scr/download/ download the appropriate .deb and install it with `gdebi skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.10_i386.deb`)

Now you can open the program from a Accessories folder and should appear in your system tray. From here, you can open Skype and the call recorder will interact with it while it's running. You'll be able to choose your settings from the menu and set up recording. [Here are some](http://atdot.ch/scr/faq/) FAQs from the website.

Comment: The ppa does not work any longer (at least for me): http://ppa.launchpad.net/dajhorn/skype-call-recorder/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
The .deb can be downloaded and installed  at http://atdot.ch/scr/download/

Comment: @Weidenrinde u have a solve for this problem?

Comment: @Pestrnko: Eh, yes.  "The .deb can be downloaded and installed at atdot.ch/scr/download "

Comment: This doesn't work any more as of Oct '17 - there's a new version of Skype for Ubuntu, which is no longer compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [this package](https://askubuntu.com/a/489625/324302)

[image]

Select these two checkboxes and select `User defined audio source` from drop-down.

Comment: Audio Recorder is pretty and simple tool - exactly what I needed. Thank you!