# Recording phone calls

Tags: skype, phone, voip

Does anyone know how I can record audio from a VOIP phone call? I've tried to do it before, and all I get is my side of the conversation. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Skype, and Sound Recorder.

Comment: Some sound cards let you record the audio being produced by it, some don't. You could reliably get this nailed using Pulseaudio by combining several sinks to a loopback. See for example http://blog.nirbheek.in/2012/12/pulseaudio-and-avconv-to-record-voip.html

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/59354/how-can-i-record-skype-conversations

Answer (score 5):

To record Skype calls, especially if you're using Ubuntu 12.04, I recommend [Skype Call Recorder](http://atdot.ch/scr/). (Currently the PPA that provides it easily on Ubuntu hasn't been updated to provide builds for Ubuntu releases past 12.04 LTS, but that's not a problem if you're using 12.04.)

To install Skype Call Recorder on Ubuntu, the easiest way is probably [to use this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dajhorn/+archive/skype-call-recorder). One way to enable this PPA and install Skype Call Recorder is to open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dajhorn/skype-call-recorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype-call-recorder
```

Skype Call Recorder is easy to use, and in my experience records with excellent sound quality. You should be aware that *there may be other utilities also called Skype Call Recorder*.

If you're not familiar with PPA's, then before taking any Internet advice to install a PPA (even my advice), please make sure to read [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo) For more general information about PPA's, see [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: I believe this is the best answer, but as of early 2014 I don't think the ppa works.  I hate to completely change the answer (I could be wrong and your rep is scary high) but since this is the right one it seems like updating would be more correct than another answer.  I followed the leading at http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/automatically-record-skype-calls-linux-skype-call-recorder.html Any thoughts, am I mistaken?

Comment: @Dennis Please feel free to edit this answer *or* to post your own separate answer! (Whichever you prefer.) If you choose to edit that makes my answer better and I can always edit it again myself if there are details I want to change. If you choose to post your own answer, you can get rep for it. Either way is good. I'm pretty busy today so I may not have a change to put more attention to this ...so if you know a way that fixes or improves on this, I'd encourage you to edit this or to post your own answer. Thanks!

Comment: The ppa does not work any longer (at least for me): ppa.launchpad.net/dajhorn/skype-call-recorder/ubuntu/dists/… 404 Not Found The .deb can be downloaded and installed at atdot.ch/scr/download