# How to record IM conversations

Tags: skype

I wonder if there's any tool by which I can record my audio/video conversations in Skype or Google Talk!

My Ubuntu version: 12.04
Skype version: 4.2.0.11
Google Talk Plugin: 4.2.1.0
Webcam: Logitech C525

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Well, I think that any [screen recorder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast) can do the job.

Comment: To record audio, see [Recording phone calls](http://askubuntu.com/questions/322397/recording-phone-calls). (Since we have that question, you might consider editing this to make it specifically about recording video.)