# Ubuntu Settings Add Recording Device

Tags: sound, settings, system-settings, devices, input-devices

I want to add my internal audio as a recording device so I can record my mic and the computer audio (while wearing headphones) in Audacity.

I'm opening up the sound settings in Ubuntu to get to the following page

[image]

How can I add my internal audio to the list here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern sound adapters have output monitoring channels. Unity/Gnome default sound settings tool (part of unity-/gnome-control-center) does not list them on input tab.

1. Install PulseAudio volume control tool (part of upstream project)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
   ```
2. Run it and go to *Input Devices* tab.
3. Look down to the right corner, *Show:* drop list, set it to *`All Input Devices`* (Default: *`All Except Monitors`*)
4. As it shows up, you can set it as default.

   [image: picture: pulseaudio volume control - show the monitor lines]

If you can't find it, then either it is not supported by driver or hardware itself. You may need to create a virtual loopback.

Comment: Interesting . As a side note,  after selecting   "monitor of builtin audio" in "output devices" (and clicking "default" near it) as indicated , i had to select  once this input in "recording" tab while Audacity is recording "pulse" input.   (look like "default" green button does not work )

Comment: @laugeo, yep by default, it will not change a current  running stream (audacity in pause or record state) and will change otherwise. I think that the expected behavior, because you don't want it to change all you previous streams if you have complicated setup to do , example speak with a friend through skype and stream some music to other trough hangout or may be a radio ...  simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

[This wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/record_system_sound) covers how to create a dummy audio input using PulseAudio, which can then be recording using Audacity.

It uses the PulseAudio Volume Controller (which is available in the default repos, `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`), and creates an application stream which Audacity will read as input.

It is much better explained on the above wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost check the Mic by recording and running the following command in a terminal window:

Make sure the device is not set to Mute, then type

> ***arecord test.wav***

and speaking into your microphone. To stop this command press `Ctrl+C`.

This will test basic recording functionality by creating test.wav in your HOME directory. Open this file to determine whether you successfully captured audio when using the `arecord` command. This may not work if the system has not detected your input device as default.

**NOTE:** If this fails, in some cases you may need to configure your ALSA setup or by [troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) as per the instructions.

**In Audacity:**

Go to menu: Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Devices. Go to section Recording

Choose the appropriate recording device (make sure the device is plugged-in)
Click OK

Now Record the audio,Then You should see the audio sensor responding and you should be able to playback the audio.

Else, Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489596/voice-recorder-for-14-04#trythis) (#Mitch)